# How can I suppress default "Python" menu in MacOS/tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am executing the following code with python 3.6 on MacOS 10.15.4. I expected a blank menu bar, or perhaps just the Apple logo menu. But I get the Apple logo plus a "Python" menu with some odd behavior (e.g. "About Python" brings up an "about" page for Tcl/Tk). Why is this showing up and how can I suppress it?

Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
mb = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=mb)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can remove it but it can be changed with something else. Also, I think every mac app has that one menu option after the apple logo, you can check that by running different apps and also see in other python GUI libraries.

Comment: Here's a good reference: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html#Platform%20Menus. Scroll down to "Platform Menus".